# ASP.NET Entity Framework MySql migration

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this relatively big database for my website, currently in a MySQL database. As the site has been based on "one size fits all" solutions so far, the recent explosive growth of the website forced me to start developing a more fitting, more optimized and less fragmented platform.

Currently working on the back-end, for which an ASP.NET API suits me the best. I've decided to go with MySQL and use the Entity Framework to set things up. While it wasn't too much of an issue, I want to migrate all the data into a new, cleaner and better set up database. The issue is the users themselves - while I think ASP's Membership might be the best solution for me, I'm not sure how to migrate all my users' needed data to the new database, or even if Memberships are actually the best way to go about this. And this is what I need help in - could someone help me how to set up the API for this?

Edit: I've designed the new database inside Visual Studio with the EF Designer, but considering all the material I find, I suppose that's an issue? >_>

Comment: So your question is _"How to use ASP.NET Membership with MySQL"_?

Comment: How to use ASP.NET Membership with MySQL as well as how to migrate users from a MySQL database to another MySQL database with ASP.NET Membership

Comment: If possible, I would recommend choosing Microsoft Sql Server and using the Database Project type built into visual studio for your database.  It is 100% easier to manage a database doing so, and supports database publishing.  You can use EF's database first approach, or instead go with PetaPoco and it's T4 Templates to generate your data layer.  In my experience, anytime one is to use .Net for something internal (not a distributed product, and is an asp.net based website, always choose MS Sql, due to it's integration with visual studio, saves a TON of time).